# Storing pointers to strsep() return values

Tags: c, string, tokenize, strsep

When I use strsep() to iterate through the tokens of a string, is it safe for me to store pointers to those tokens, and refer to them later? Example:

```
char str[] = "some word tokens";
char *sameStr = str;
char *token, *old1, *old2;

token = strsep(&sameStr, " ");
old1 = token;

token = strsep(&sameStr, " ");
old2 = token;

token = strsep(&sameStr, " ");

printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", token, old1, old2);
```

It seems like strsep() always modifies the original character array, inserting null characters after each token. If so, I should be safe storing and later using the **old1** and **old2** pointers, right? Also, does my use of **sameStr** cause any problems? I can't use the pointer **str** directly due to strsep() expecting a restricted char** type.

Comment: Not only *seems* like it overwrite the contents in the string you pass. It *definitely* does that. From [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html): "This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a null byte ('\0')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stored pointers will be valid until the original string goes out of scope. Until then, you can access them however you need to. The use of `sameStr` shouldn't cause any problems.